# how can update my mysql database on facebook login using javascript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to be able to enter the users details from facebook into my database on login, heres the script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({appId: '<?=$fbconfig['appid' ]?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

                /* All the events registered */
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    // do something with response
                    login();
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                    // do something with response
                    logout();
                });
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());

            function login(){
                document.location.href = "<?=$config['baseurl']?>";
            }
            function logout(){
                document.location.href = "<?=$config['baseurl']?>";
            }
</script>
```

this script works fine and i can login and logout from my application using facebook, but say for instance i want to enter some details like users email  from facebook into the database, would i use ajax to achieve that? 
im thining to do an ajax call on the function login(), wuld that be possible,
p.s. dont worry i have already set the permission to access users email :)) thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is is to get hold of the email address, or is it sending it to the server so that you can store it?

Comment: getting hold of the email address and then sending it to the server, i know how to do an ajax request using jquery, but how do get hold of the data like name and email adress :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some server-side code to write changes to the database and you need to call this server-side code from JS using some kind of AJAX-request.

I.e: If you use PHP have a look at [this](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) for the server side. For the JS side I would recomment using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), a JS toolkit which makes it really easy to do AJAX calls. And of course you need some kind of protocol to wrap your data - have a look at [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).